# Testing OpportunityLineItem Error in Name?

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

I am having issues entering an OpportunityLineItem in a test class and getting the below error.

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Name]:
>   [Name]

```
OpportunityLineItem OLI = new OpportunityLineItem(
        Media_Plan_Line_Item__c =[select id from CustomObject__c
                                                              //  where EDHOpLineItem__c != null 
                                                                 WHERE DoNotSync__c = FALSE
                                  and name !=''
                                  and custom__Name__c !=''
                                  AND Custom_ProductType__c != 'Display'

                                                                LIMIT 1].id,

      custom_StartDate__c = system.now(),
      custom_StartDate__c= system.now(),
      custom__DC_EndDate__c = system.now(),   
      custom_EndDate__c= system.now(),
          custom__DSM_ProdName__c = 'woof',
          Opportunityid =[select id from Opportunity limit 1].id,
          Quantity =1,
          PricebookEntryId = '01u3800000MSUqAAAX',
          TotalPrice = 0
      );
     insert OLI;
```

This is not a writable field.

> Field is not writeable: OpportunityLineItem.Name

Please advise.

Here is the error from debug- I have the finest available debug level and it doesn't tell me what page is giving the error:

> 15:19:14.0 (936442270)|VF_PAGE_MESSAGE|Required fields are missing:
>   [Name] 15:19:14.0
>   (936495278)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[28]|System.DmlException: Insert failed.
>   First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING,
>   Required fields are missing: [Name]: [Name]

Comment: Are you sure that the error `System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Name]: [Name]` is coming from Opportunity Line item? A debug log will be really helpful to see if there is any other code which is causing this. There are a lot of other things to check based on the documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm

Comment: thanks i have updated

Comment: The line copied from your debug log doesn't necessarily indicate the error comes from trying to insert the OLI object. Name is indeed read only on OLI, therefore this exception won't make sense. Can you try to refine your debug to understand where this exception is coming from?

Comment: `OpportunityLineItem.Name` is in effect, a formula field on the Product2.Name referenced by the hard-coded `pricebookentryId` you are using.  This `pricebookentryid` must belong to the same pricebook as on the parent opportunity (and best practice is to query for it).  verify your code under test is at least v30 and you've enabled Pricebooks and Products for Opportunities in the org